# Not able to kill mysql process with "kill -9 <pid>"

Tags: mysql, macos

I am on Macbook, on terminal I try to find which app is occupying port 3306. I run command:

```
sudo lsof -i TCP:3306
```

I got output:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  47730 _mysql   19u  IPv6 0x736b0ff006adfb97      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

Then, I kill the process by `sudo kill -9 47730`. It executed without error.

But then, I run sudo lsof -i TCP:3306 again, I got:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  47759 _mysql   19u  IPv6 0x736b0ff006ae0cd7      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

the mysql process is up again with different PID,  why? How can I permanently kill MySQL process on my Macbook?

(mysql  Version 8.0.11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/osx-installation-launchd.html

MySQL Server on MacOS is configured as a Launch Daemon, with a "KeepAlive" option enabled. That means if it stops, for example when you use `kill -9`, MacOS will restart it automatically.

You should stop it using the System Preferences widget (shown on the manual page I linked to), or with `launchctl`.

If you installed MySQL Server using `brew` or by some other means, it might not be managed by `launchctl`.

For example, some people use `supervisord` to run the MySQL Server, in which case you can stop it with `supervisorctl stop mysql`.

When using a non-launchctl method of running MySQL Server, it might be running [mysqld_safe](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqld-safe.html), which is a script that automatically restarts mysqld if it's killed or crashes. That's why you have to shut down mysqld_safe properly.

When I run test instances of MySQL Server on my Macbook, I start them with [dbdeployer](https://www.dbdeployer.com), which launches a mysqld_safe process.

MacOS can be a confusing environment for MySQL Server, because there are several ways to acquire and run it, and each one has its own way of managing the process.

Comment: Helped my issue by turning off MySQL from system preferences of macbook.

Answer (score 0):

That process seems to be **owned by another user** `_mysql`. To kill it, try doing

```
sudo -u _mysql -c kill -9 47730
```

- `-u` is for the *user*
- `-c` is for the *command*

## Note

- If that doesn't work you can always try `sudo kill -9 47730` (run as root, but it's a bit of an overkill)
- Also since you're on a *Mac*, you can try `brew services stop mysql` to shut down the service more gracefully. That's if you're using `homebrew`

Comment: I mean, overkill would probably be `sudo reboot -h now`. running as root here where you (as a superuser of the computer) want something to end, and know the process being ended, seems like extra work to hunt down the potential username involved.